# Как лучше поступить с генерацией html?

Tags: html, ajax, json

Всем привет! Есть проект, данные с базы получаются без перезагрузки страницы (т.е. общение frontenda с backend'ом происходит через AJAX). Вот тут и главный вопрос: где лучше генерировать содержимое сайта в html?

Есть 2 варианта:

1. Генерировать всё на стороне backend'а и передавать в готовом виде.
2. Передавать данные в JSON'e, и уже на стороне клиента генерировать содержимое, например каким-то шаблонизатором.

Подскажите пожалуйста, какой с вариантов лучше? И если не сложно, опишите плюсы и минусы каждого с вариантов. Всем спасибо за понимание.

Comment: Я бы возвращал JSON и генерил разметку на фронте. Сгенеренная разметка на бэке - это уже веб формы какие-то...

Comment: Нынче в моде вариант 2, но я и как пользователь, и как разработчик его ненавижу и делаю вариант 1

Comment: полностью поддерживаю andreymal . это намного проще и на клиенте отрабатывает намного быстее. и кода меньше - следовательно загрузка мтраницы быстрее. я только передаю не через ajax, а с по websocket.

Comment: И тонкий клиент превращается в толстый. Так не лучше ли сделать нормальное настольное приложение? На фига html, браузер?

Comment: @Sergey современным "нормальным настольным приложением" уже несколько лет как считается приложение на html/css/js, уже много таких :(